# Firebase push notification ( Services don't called from the manifest when i launch the application )

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Firebase Services in AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
 <service
     android:name="com.MyApp.app.services.MyFirebaseIDService"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.MyApp.app.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**My Gradle Libs :**

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar.jar'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
compile 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
compile 'com.wdullaer:swipeactionadapter:2.0.0'}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**I've Added onCreate on my firebase classes :**

```
   @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v("Test", "Service Created");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer i've finally find the solution. I've integrated this Library : **'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'** that use the same ***app_name*** as my application so the solution was to Add in my AndroidManifast.xml => **tools:node="replace"** :

```
 <application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    tools:node="replace">
```

So the solution was to remove this line and modify the app_name on the external Library.

Answer (score 0):

`MyFirebaseMessagingService`'s `onMessageReceived` will be called only when the device receives a push notification from FCM. The service is always running in the background.

`MyFirebaseIDService` will be created only when you launch your application for the first time. It creates the instance of the service and creates a token from `onTokenRefresh` method. All subsequent launches will not create this service. Instead `onTokenRefresh` method will be called whenever the token is refreshed in the background.

Therefore you might not be able to see the log messages in `onCreate` method of these services.

You may see the message if you clear app data ( from `Settings->Apps->AppName->Storage->clear data` ) & then launch the application.